# Service OR IntentService playing audio after recording

Tags: android, service, intentservice, android-intentservice

I want to achieve following goals:

- Record Audio
- Send Audio to Server
- Play Audio

I know that First 2 tasks are possible by Using **Service** as I've done that in one of the previous apps but when it comes to playing an audio file, it needs to be triggered from an Activity.

Because accessing Activity from Service can be achieved by using *BroadcastReceiver* but what about accessing method of a Service from an Activity?

So, now comes the question: Whether to go for **Service** itself for *Playing the audio also(triggered from activity)* OR  to use **IntentService**.

Documentation says,

> *No easy or direct way to interact with user interface directly from IntentService.*

and

> *Any tasks started using IntentService cannot be interrupted*

I may want to stop recording ant time and play it any time.

Which would suit t he requirement best --> **Service**  OR  **IntentService** ??

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can upload audio using intent service and play your audio on the ui thread in activity. Since the audio is recorded you can save it and play it on the ui thread

Comment: What will the factor for choosing IntentService over Service for recording and uploading?

Comment: read the docs.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html

Comment: But as already mentioned in the question, recording end may be triggered from an activity while doc says "Any tasks started using IntentService cannot be interrupted"

Comment: i said use intent service for uploading once audio is recorded. The playing can be done on the ui thread

Comment: I understood abt playing audio on ui thread. What abt recording it?

Comment: @GAMA : **"...playing an audio file, it needs to be triggered from an Activity."** : Why? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @Squonk  - I'll start service from an activity, service will record the audio. But when to play that audio is decided by the service based on some event (Hence, the phrase, triggered from an activity)

Comment: @GAMA : OK, when you said "...it needs to be..." I thought you believed it was a restriction of Android but instead you mean it is a requirement of your app design. Correct?

Comment: Yes. You understood it correctly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use a `Service` rather than an `IntentService` for what you need.

In particular, use a bound `Service` which allows two-way communication between the `Activity` which binds to it and from the `Service` to the `Activity`.

The `IntentService` class is designed for one-shot operations using its own worker thread, once the work on the thread is complete, the thread terminates and the `IntentService` calls `stopSelf()` to terminate itself. This means any user interaction between the user (via an `Activity`) and an `IntentService` is problematic.

A bound `Service` on the other hand will exist until it is either explicitly stopped or untill the last bound component unbinds. This allows for longer term interaction.

For playback, the fact a `Service` runs on the UI thread isn't an issue if you use something like `MediaPlayer`which handles its own thread for playback purposes.

Further to this, if you use a bound `Service`, `MediaPlayer` and `MediaController`, you can control play, stop, pause, seek etc from the `Activity`.

EDIT: For further information see... [Bound Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html)

Comment: Perfect. Can u give a brief idea abt what you mean by "bound service"?

Comment: @GAMA : I can only point you at the guide for bound services on the Android devs site (see the edit it at the bottom of my answer). It looks complex but it's not that bad. Ignore any stuff about IPC and AIDL as they're for accessing Services in other processes. Creating a bound Service in your own app is quite straight-forward.

Comment: Will this be a good reference point: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Android_Local_Bound_Services_%E2%80%93_A_Worked_Example ??

Comment: @GAMA : Yes, that looks like a good basic explanation and example. Once you have an understanding of the `Binder` and `ServiceConnection` concepts, using bound services is quite straight-forward. Good luck.

Comment: @GAMA here's another https://thenewcircle.com/s/post/60/servicesdemo_using_android_services that shows how to have a bounded service.